# Options for executing an arbitrary function from my wallet

Tags: metamask, contract-invocation

What are my options if I want to call an arbitrary function at an arbitrary address, from my wallet (Metamask)?

To be more precise, I want to be able to call a function from a web wallet, when I have the following ingredients:

1. I know the contract address
2. I know the function signature and know what parameters I want to use
3. I don't have the full ABI
4. The contract isn't verified in Etherscan, or something like that

Is my best option to write an interface, create a dumb website and connect my Metamask to it? Or to figure out the payload data and execute directly in Metamask? Aren't there some easier ways?

Answer (score 1):

If the function name and parameters are known it should be possible to create a dummy contract and generate a minimal ABI with Remix. Then use Remix connected to Metamask or a wallet like MyEtherWallet and MyCrypto.